# What's an easy way to dynamically generate some JavaScript in Seaside?

Tags: seaside

I'm trying to add Disqus to a blog I'm writing.  To deal with Seaside sessions I need to either add a unique discus_identifier or disqus_url to the JS.  I overrode my component's #script method but it can only return a string literal.

I see two options:

1. Dynamically generate the JS, save it to a file, and load that file in to my component.
2. Add a permalink for each blog entry.

Is there an easier way?  Or is one (or both) of these ways easy to do? I'm new to Smalltalk and Seaside and am unsure how to accomplish either of these two things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is an easier way. You can generate the correct Discus JS code directly in the #script method. It should return a String literal but you can create this String on the fly. For example by using a WriteStream.

You blog entries also need a permalink. You can use the #initialRequest: method to handle these permalinks.

Comment: Thanks jan, had a silly error concatenating my JS strings.  Is there a tutorial on creating clean URLs in Seaside? I found one on Ramon Leon's blog but the information appears to be outdated (the first method override is now deprecated).

Answer (score 1):

### dynamic javascript stuff

if I'm right, that's the kind of scenario you'll get for things like retweet buttons too. (which is the thing I have at hand to provide you examples of).

What I did in my blog is a little specialized seaside component named BITRetweet that you configure with the permalink (and username and style preference). Forget the files stuff (that will only complicate things), everything is on the fly. It renders with this:

BITRetweet>>renderContentOn: html

```
html script with: self customizedJavascript.
html script url: self buttonJavascriptSource.
```

BITRetweet>>customizedJavascript

```
| script |

script := JSScript new.

script add: (('"',self permalink,'"') asJSObject assignTo: 'tweetmeme_url').

isCompact ifTrue:[
    script add: ('"compact"' asJSObject assignTo: 'tweetmeme_style')].

script add: (('"',username,'"') asJSObject assignTo: 'tweetmeme_source').
script add: (('"',shortener,'"') asJSObject assignTo: 'tweetmeme_service').

^ script
```

BITRetweet>>>buttonJavascriptSource

```
"Answers the url to the source of the script for the button.
See: 
http://help.tweetmeme.com/2009/04/06/tweetmeme-button/"

^ 'http://tweetmeme.com/i/scripts/button.js'
```

and finally a little hack for String, like this:

String>>asJSObject

```
^ JSObject new alias: self
```

### working with permalinks

for the permalink part, there are two things:

1. generating it
2. using it (making the app to react when the request comes with it)

**for 1 you can do something like this:**

`PostComponent>>updateUrl: anUrl`

```
super updateUrl: anUrl.

anUrl addToPath: model asURLNice
```

Post>>asURLNice

```
"Answers the receiver in an (destructive) encoded 
way which is url friendly"

^ String streamContents: [:stream|
    self do:[:char|
        char isSeparator 
            ifTrue:[stream nextPut: $-]
            ifFalse:[
                char isAlphaNumeric ifTrue:[
                    stream nextPut: char asLowercase asNonDiacritical]]]]
```

and **for 2 you have to do something like this** in your main application component:

BlogApplication>>initialRequest: aRequestOrNil

```
| paths |

super initialRequest: aRequestOrNil.

aRequestOrNil ifNil:[^ nil].

(aRequestOrNil url asString endsWith: '/sitemap.xml') ifTrue:[
    ^ self respondSitemap].

paths := aRequestOrNil url path.
paths size < 2 ifTrue:[^nil].

(Post atURLTitle: paths last) ifNotNilDo: [:value | 
    ^ self readPost:  value].
```

### live examples

you can see all that in action in [my blog](http://sebastianconcept.com) or in [selective creativity](http://blog.flowingconcept.com)
the asNonDiacritical is needed for me because I blog trilingual but the DiacriticalSupport is available in [squeaksource](http://squeaksource.com) if you need it

have fun hacking

o/